# Can I trigger Alexa to respond based on an API / Job call?

Tags: alexa

I have a requirement where I would like the Echo to trigger a conversation using an API that I have. The API is running on the web server and based on a condition it should trigger the Echo device (Alexa) by prompting a question to the end user of the given device. 
Workflow would like:

API --> Triggers an Echo Device (of a specific user) --> Asks a question --> User answers the question --> Alexa invokes X API.

Answer (score 3):

No, the user needs to start the interaction, mainly because you have no way of knowing if there is anybody in the room with the Alexa, but also because this would be incredibly annoying.